# Expo/React Native - Can't redirect to homescreen after login

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am working on a mobile app with Expo/React Native and trying to have a login screen for sign in. Once signed in,the user will be redirected to the homescreen.

However I have not been able to configure it with setting the state upon successful gaining the credentials for "isLoggedIn:true." On the stack navigator, I tried to set it up where it will show different screens (Home and Third Screen) if logged in while the LoginScreen will be if logged in is false. How do I configure it to properly redirect to the homescreen upon successful login.

```
export default function App() {
const [state, setstate] = useState({
   isSignedIn:false,
 })

 return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>

  {state.isSignedIn == false ? ( 
    <>
    <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={LoginScreen} />
    </>  
  ) : (
    <>
    <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeStack} options={({ route }) => ({
headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route) })} />

    <Stack.Screen name='ThirdScreen' component={ThirdScreen}/>
    </>
  )}

   </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
 );
}
```

Below is my code for the login on the LoginScreen.js:

```
 render() {
function handleSubmit({ props }) {

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('username',this.state.username);
  formData.append('password',this.state.password);

  fetch('<My login API from the server side>', {
    method: 'POST',
    body:formData
  }).then(response => {
    if(response.status == 200) {
      response.body.getReader().read().then(({value, done}) => {
        const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8')
        const keyitems = decoder.decode(value);
        //convert to JSON
        const obj = JSON.parse(keyitems);

        //get individual values from string
        this.setState({ 
          userToken:obj.key.toString(),
          username:obj.user.username,
          user_id:obj.user.id,
          user_image:obj.user.userprofile.user_image,
          isSignedIn:true
        }) 
        //refresh or redirect to hopefully get to home
        //assuming the state has been switched to logged
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
      })

    } else { 
      //issue alert to say try again
      console.log("bad")
    }
  });

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62006478/react-navigation-in-react-native-with-conditional-stack-and-authentication/62007332?noredirect=1#comment109815956_62007332

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to navigate to the Home screen manually by calling navigation.navigate('Home'). React Navigation will automatically navigate to the Home screen when isSignedIn becomes true.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

It seems like you have written a hook call 'setstate' but you have not used that in the child component. To make it work, you would need to pass the function argument of the hook in the parent component to the child component and call that to set the signed in state.

Try modifying your code like this

```
   export default function App() {
const [state, setState] = useState({
   isSignedIn:false,
 })

 return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>

  {state.isSignedIn == false ? ( 
    <>
    <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={LoginScreen} setState={setState} />
    </>  
  ) : (
    <>
    <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeStack} options={({ route }) => ({
headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route) })} />

    <Stack.Screen name='ThirdScreen' component={ThirdScreen}/>
    </>
  )}

   </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
 );
}
```

and

```
render() {
function handleSubmit({ props }) {

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('username',this.state.username);
  formData.append('password',this.state.password);

  fetch('<My login API from the server side>', {
    method: 'POST',
    body:formData
  }).then(response => {
    if(response.status == 200) {
      response.body.getReader().read().then(({value, done}) => {
        const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8')
        const keyitems = decoder.decode(value);
        //convert to JSON
        const obj = JSON.parse(keyitems);

        //get individual values from string
        props.setState({ 
          userToken:obj.key.toString(),
          username:obj.user.username,
          user_id:obj.user.id,
          user_image:obj.user.userprofile.user_image,
          isSignedIn:true
        }) 
      })

    } else { 
      //issue alert to say try again
      console.log("bad")
    }
  });

 }
```